# Gon watch not working Rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to use [gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon). I'm able to use `gon.variable_name` in my controllers but when I write `gon.watch.variable_name` it throws error:

```
undefined method `variable_name=' for nil:NilClass
```

I've included `gon` in my `application.html.erb` as:

```
<%= include_gon(:init => true) %>
```

What is wrong here?

Update: Even [in the wiki](https://github.com/gazay/gon/wiki/Usage-gon-watch), it says same way to use it

Comment: Maybe the include line should be: `<%= include_gon(init: true, watch: true) %>`? Tell us if that works.

Comment: already tried that. same result.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
<%= Gon::Base.render_data %>
```

instead of:

```
<%= include_gon(:init => true) %>
```

?

Answer (score 0):

In your rails file, it should be formatted as gon.watch.variable_name, but not in your .js file.

In your .js file, it should be formatted like so:

```
gon.watch('variable_name', function() {});
```

If for example you were getting a list of tasks from your TasksController, you would put:

```
gon.watch.tasks = Task.all
```

And in your .js file:

```
gon.watch('tasks', function(tasks) {
  //do something with tasks
});
```